# How to get the ID from an active element, and change it to match another ID?

Tags: jquery, html

I am making a timeline for a school-project. The idea is that when hovering over an element, a description of that year will appear. What I am trying to do is make a code that transforms the ID of the active element, to the ID of the element that is supposed to be shown. What I have so far is:

```
<div class='timeline-element' id='year-1492'>
            <p>1492</p>
        </div>
        <div class='timeline-element' id='year-1607'>
            <p>1607</p>
        </div>
        <div class='timeline-element' id='year-1620'>
            <p>1620</p>
        </div>
```

and 30 more years.

What is is suposed to activate:

```
<div class='timeline-info-panels'>
        <div class='timeline-info' id='1492'>
            <p>1492 info</p>
        </div>
        <div class='timeline-info' id='1607'>
            <p>1607 info</p>
        </div>
        <div class='timeline-info' id='1620'>
            <p>1620 info</p>
        </div>
</div>
```

and 30 more info panels

The jQuery:

```
$('.timeline-element').hover(function(){


    $(this).addClass('hover-over-time-pill')
    $('.timeline-info-panels').show();

    var hoverID=$(this).attr("id");
    var newID=$(hoverID).replace('year-', ' ')
    $('#'+newID).show();
},
function(){
    $('.timeline-info').hide();
    $('.timeline-info-panels').hide();
    $(this).removeClass('hover-over-time-pill');
    $('#'+newID).hide();
    });
```

This is not working, and I have no idea what to do, as I am quite new to HTML and jQuery.
So basically, the question is: How do I do this?

Comment: You have missing semicolons in your hover functions. first fix them.

Comment: @lolka_bolka JavaScript semi-colons aren't mandatory in JavaScript. "Fixing" them will not do anything.

Comment: `newID` is undefined in your second function, and your replace is going to take `year-xxxx` and produce `[space]xxxx`, which doesn't exist in your html.

Comment: would have to parse the ID again in second function of `hover` also. As noted don't add a space

Comment: What do you mean by: "to the ID of the element that is supposed to be shown".?

Comment: Are you sure that you want to be changing IDs? I'm not sure that's a great idea. I'd suggest changing/adding/removing classes instead.

Comment: @lolka_bolka: Those will get handled by (the horror that is) Automatic Semicolon Insertion. But yes, best to provide them explicitly.

Comment: You could use data-id="1234", they could easily be switched for values

Comment: Maybe you should consider using the tooltip? It will show some info when you hover over.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you make a [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/)?

First problem is a space in your code.

```
var newID=$(hoverID).replace('year-', ' ')
$('#'+newID).show();
```

`newID` would looke like this `" test"`. So `$('#'+newID)` will throw an error, because there is no `"# test"` element, only a `#test`.

Second one... can you provide a little bit more code? Like a `.timeline-info-panels` e.g.

---

EDIT:

Made a [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/4f2xcp5b/) and fixed some of the bugs in your JS code.

e.g. hoverID is already a string, so you write this line:

```
var newID = $(hoverID).replace('year-', ' ')
```

like this:

```
var newID = hoverID.replace('year-', '')
```

Comment: Comments should be comments, not part of your answer. (E.g., asking for a fiddle, etc.) The part of your answer related to the `id` is, of course, an answer.

Comment: have added the info panels

Answer (score 1):

Three problems:

- a space in the replace function will give you wrong IDs (`" 1942"` vs. `"1942"`)
- newID not defined in the "unhover" callback function - either move the variable up the scope, or redefine it (I did the latter)
- `var newID = $(hoverID).replace('year-', '')` - `$(hoverID)` should be simply `hoverID` because you've already extracted the ID string, and need no more jQuery objects

Here is a working version with the three problems from above fixed:

```js
    $('.timeline-element').hover(function(){
        
        $(this).addClass('hover-over-time-pill')
        $('.timeline-info-panels').show();
    
        var hoverID=$(this).attr("id");
        var newID = hoverID.replace('year-', ''); // THIS IS FIXED
        $('#'+newID).show();
    },
    function(){
        $('.timeline-info').hide();
        $('.timeline-info-panels').hide();
        $(this).removeClass('hover-over-time-pill');

        var hoverID=$(this).attr("id");           // THIS IS ADDED
        var newID = hoverID.replace('year-', ''); // THIS IS ADDED
        $('#'+newID).hide();
    });
```

```css
.timeline-info {
  display: none;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='timeline-element' id='year-1492'>
            <p>1492</p>
        </div>
        <div class='timeline-element' id='year-1607'>
            <p>1607</p>
        </div>
        <div class='timeline-element' id='year-1620'>
            <p>1620</p>
        </div>


<div class='timeline-info-panels'>
        <div class='timeline-info' id='1492'>
            <p>1492 info</p>
        </div>
        <div class='timeline-info' id='1607'>
            <p>1607 info</p>
        </div>
        <div class='timeline-info' id='1620'>
            <p>1620 info</p>
        </div>
</div>
```

BONUS

Not sure if replacing IDs is the part of your assignment, but see how much easier it can get if you directly match IDs to something else (I used a class, but using `data-*` attributes is great, too):

```js
$('.timeline-element').hover(function(){
        $('.'+ $(this).attr('id') ).show();
    },
    function(){
        $('.'+ $(this).attr('id') ).hide();
    });
```

```css
.timeline-info {
  display: none;
  padding: 10px;
  background: #eee;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='timeline-element' id='year-1492'>
            <p>1492</p>
        </div>
        <div class='timeline-element' id='year-1607'>
            <p>1607</p>
        </div>
        <div class='timeline-element' id='year-1620'>
            <p>1620</p>
        </div>


<div class='timeline-info-panels'>
        <div class='timeline-info year-1492'>
            <p>1492 info</p>
        </div>
        <div class='timeline-info year-1607'>
            <p>1607 info</p>
        </div>
        <div class='timeline-info year-1620'>
            <p>1620 info</p>
        </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of issues there.

1. As [Dev Vampyr highlighted](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26974950/157247), your code is replacing `year-` in the ID with a space, and so when you go to look up the element, your CSS selector is invalid (it looks like `# 1234` rather than `#1234`).
2. CSS ID selectors *cannot* start with a digit (even though the `id` attribute in HTML can), so `#1234` would also be invalid. jQuery tolerates them provided they're on their own (e.g., `$("#1234")` works but `$("#1234 div")` doesn't), but that's not a documented feature and so could disappear at any time. Although it's possible to escape the selector to make it valid, it's a pain, so the best thing really is not to use `id`s that start with digits.
3. `newID` is a local variable in your first function, it's not accessible in your second function.

So I'd probably change the HTML so the `id`s start with a letter, like say `t`:

```
<div class='timeline-info-panels'>
        <div class='timeline-info' id='t1492'>
            <p>1492 info</p>
        </div>
        <div class='timeline-info' id='t1607'>
            <p>1607 info</p>
        </div>
        <div class='timeline-info' id='t1620'>
            <p>1620 info</p>
        </div>
</div>
```

And then update the code not to use the space, but to add a `t`:

```
$('.timeline-element').hover(function() {

        $(this).addClass('hover-over-time-pill');
        $('.timeline-info-panels').show();

        var hoverID = this.id; // `$(this).attr("id")` is just a long way of doing `this.id`
        var newID = $(hoverID).replace('year-', 't')
        $('#' + newID).show();
    },
    function() {
        $('.timeline-info').hide();
        $('.timeline-info-panels').hide();
        $(this).removeClass('hover-over-time-pill');;
        var hoverID = this.id;
        var newID = $(hoverID).replace('year-', 't')
        $('#' + newID).hide();
    }
);
```

You don't need `replace` either, really, since you're combining this with `#` later anyways, so you could just use `substring`, and we can condense that logic a bit:

```
$('.timeline-element').hover(function() {

        $(this).addClass('hover-over-time-pill');
        $('.timeline-info-panels').show();
        $('#t' + this.id.substring(5)).show();
    },
    function() {
        $('.timeline-info').hide();
        $('.timeline-info-panels').hide();
        $(this).removeClass('hover-over-time-pill');;
        $('#t' + this.id.substring(5)).hide();
    }
);
```

---

Side note: I see you're adding a class to the hovered element when you start hovering and then removing it when you stop hovering. There's no need for that; instead, in your CSS, just associate rules with `.timeline-element:hover` and let the browser handle it for you.